# Problems Locking within Called Instance Methods

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have been going through the albahari threading lessons but when I went to experiment on my own things did not go as planned. I have no idea why the following lock, "_Lock", is not holding up. Somehow the lock in each of SafeLock's methods is not blocking other threads from also using its methods. Been at this for quite some time so any help would be much appreciated.

```
//Here I just call a method 10x
//The method (SL1) then creates a SafeLocks object and runs 3 methods
private void SL1_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SL1(); SL1(); SL1(); SL1(); SL1();
    SL1(); SL1(); SL1(); SL1(); SL1();
}
private void SL1()
{
    console.WriteLine("Thread Enter");
    SafeLocks sl = new SafeLocks();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => sl.ShowVars());
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => sl.SetZero());
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => sl.ShowVars());
    console.WriteLine("Thread Exit");
}

//Now for the Thread-"Safe" class
    class SafeLocks
{
    //private static int staticVar = 1; 
    private static int staticVar = 1; 
    public int instanceVar = 1;
    private static readonly object _Lock = new object();

    public SafeLocks() //sets both to 100,000
    {
        lock (_Lock)
        {
            while (staticVar < 99999)
            { staticVar++; }
            while (instanceVar < 99999)
            { instanceVar++; }
            staticVar++;
            instanceVar++;
            if (instanceVar != 100000)
            { Console.WriteLine("I1=" + instanceVar.ToString()); }
            if (staticVar != 100000)
            { Console.WriteLine(("S1=" + staticVar.ToString())); }
        }
    }
    public void ShowVars()
    {
        lock (_Lock)
        {
            if (instanceVar != 100000 && instanceVar != 0)
            { Console.WriteLine("I2=" + instanceVar.ToString()); }
            if (staticVar != 100000 && staticVar != 0)
            { Console.WriteLine("S2=" + staticVar.ToString()); }
        }
    }
    public void SetZero()
    {
        lock (_Lock)
        {
            while (staticVar > 0)
            {
                staticVar--;
            }
            while (instanceVar > 0)
            {
                instanceVar--;
            }
            if (instanceVar != 0)
            { Console.WriteLine("I3=" + instanceVar.ToString()); }
            if (staticVar != 0)
            { Console.WriteLine("S3=" + staticVar.ToString()); }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Side note: I don't think there is a naming convention that enables calling any parameter `_Lock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from a combination of your constructor and the fact that there is no thread-safety between multiple instances being constructed or calling `SetZero`. That is, you could have two instances created before a call to `SetZero` is made. (EDIT: The locks that you have now *are* functioning correctly in that no method may be executed simultaneously, but they do nothing to guarantee the *order* in which those methods are being called from the outside. The threads you have setup are ultimately calling the object constructor multiple times *before* a call to `SetZero` is eventually made.)

Firstly in your constructor (note, I eliminated the `instanceVar` usage as it is functioning OK):

```
while (staticVar < 99999)
{ staticVar++; }
staticVar++;
```

This *assumes* that the `staticVar` starts at a value less than `99999` *then* increments it one more value to make it `10000`. However, *if* it was *already* `100000` *before* the constructor is executed, it will increment to `100001`.

This can be easily demonstrated by executing the following without any threading whatsoever:

```
SafeLocks sl = new SafeLocks();
SafeLocks s2 = new SafeLocks(); //outputs "S1=100001"
SafeLocks s3 = new SafeLocks(); //outputs "S1=100002"
SafeLocks s4 = new SafeLocks(); //outputs "S1=100003"
SafeLocks s5 = new SafeLocks(); //outputs "S1=100004"
```

If you change your constructor code to be:

```
lock (_Lock)
{
    while (staticVar <= 99999) //note the <= comparison change
    { staticVar++; }
    while (instanceVar <= 99999) //note the <= comparison change
    { instanceVar++; }
    if (instanceVar != 100000)
    { Console.WriteLine("I1=" + instanceVar.ToString()); }
    if (staticVar != 100000)
    { Console.WriteLine(("S1=" + staticVar.ToString())); }
}
```

The code will "work", but it still *technically* might have a bug in that there's no guarantee that you'll call `SetZero` before the constructor of the next instance is created. I am not sure if this is an issue or not for you as this is a pretty contrived design/example but something for you to be aware of in future usage. (Also, consider separating static and instance level thread safety concerns where possible) The only way to avoid it otherwise, that is, ensure that `SetZero` is called before another is constructed I believe, is non-trivial in your current design and generally speaking awkward/non-obvious anyway.

Comment: Aha! I now understand locking much better thanks to your answer. As the worker threads get created they run off into the OS stack so even though the original calling thread executed 10x in order, the order of the worker threads can be somewhat random and many of them can be getting in front of each other in an undesired fashion.

Your explanation of why this only misses to the upside was very helpful!